# How do you override a method for a java type instance with Groovy meta programming?

Tags: groovy, metaprogramming

I am trying to override the functionality of a method of a java type instance in my Groovy code but I am getting a classcast exception.

I looked at the guide posted [here](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Per-Instance+MetaClass) but I can not get it to work.

Since my actual problem is a bit of mess, below is some runnable example code that fails with the same error. 
In the example I want to override the substring method of an instance of the java.lang.String class. In reality I want to override a method of an instance of a class that does not have a corresponding Groovy implementation, so the answer to my example is not to simply use a Groovy string instance.

```
class example {
    static void main(args) {
        java.lang.String hey = new java.lang.String("hey")
        ExpandoMetaClass emc = new ExpandoMetaClass( java.lang.String, false )
            emc.substring = {
                       "This is not a very good substring implementation"
                }
            emc.initialize()

        def proxiedHey = new groovy.util.Proxy().wrap(hey)
        proxiedHey.setMetaClass(emc)
        printf proxiedHey.toString()
        printf proxiedHey.substring(1)
    }
}
```

The above example fails at line 12, i.e printf meh.toString(). The exception thrown is

> Caught: java.lang.ClassCastException:
>   groovy.util.Proxy cannot be cast to
>   java.lang.CharSequence at
>   example.main(test.groovy:12)

So, any ideas on what I am doing wrong or if there is another way to solve my problem of adding and/or overriding methods of a java type instance?

I am using Groovy version 1.7.4.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are creating an ExpandoMetaClass for `java.lang.String`, but assigning it to a `groovy.util.Proxy`.  Make a metaClass for `groovy.util.Proxy` instread, like so:

```
java.lang.String hey = new java.lang.String("hey")
def proxiedHey = new groovy.util.Proxy().wrap(hey)
ExpandoMetaClass emc = new ExpandoMetaClass( groovy.util.Proxy, false )
emc.substring = {
    "This is not a very good substring implementation"
}
emc.initialize()

proxiedHey.setMetaClass(emc)
printf proxiedHey.toString()
printf proxiedHey.substring(1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at [Pimp my Library Pattern](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Pimp+my+Library+Pattern) which allows you to add using [Groovy Categories](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Groovy+Categories). You might find it more convenient and easy to understand in your case.

```
@Category(String)
class StringSubstrCategory {      
    def substring( int n)   { 
        "This is not a very good substring implementation"
    }
}

use (StringSubstrCategory) {
    "hey".substring(1)
}
```