# How can I change Java method implementation of single instance?

Tags: java, groovy, metaprogramming

What is correct way to change method signature for single *java object*. Suppose I wanna change `toString` method.

```
myObject.metaClass.toString = { pritln "hello world" }
```

Looks like this code has problems. If I pass my object into other Java compiled object original `toString` will be called.

Other [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4035784/how-do-you-override-a-method-for-a-java-type-instance-with-groovy-meta-programmi) creates wrapper `Object`. It has different class from original one so it doesn't satisfy me

---

**Added:**
1. I can't control creation process
2. I don't know how object was instantiated

So there is no ***groovy way*** to solve this problem?
The only solution is to create Java wrapper class, wrap all methods and change one? This is a ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

any changes you make to the metaClass are only visible to groovy.

java has no idea the metaClass exists, so obviously cannot call any replacement methods defined by it

Answer (score 4):

If you would like to create an object that has a single method changed, there is a way to do that using "Anonymous Classes".

Whenever creating your object:

```
MyClass myObject = new MyClass() {
    public String toString() {
        ...implementation...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Can you use an annoymous subclass? That will only override the `toString()` method in that single instance.

```
MyObject myObject= new MyObject (){
    @Override
    public String toString (){
         println "hello world"
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a Wrapper that extends the Original:

```
public class wrapper extends myObject{
    public toString{
        System.out.println("hello world");
    }
}
```

Comment: OP stated he didn't want to use a wrapper class.