# Can I do this with ExpandoMetaClasses in Groovy?

Tags: groovy, metaprogramming

When upgrading from Groovy 1.8.4 to 1.8.5 the JsonSlurper returns a BigDecimal instead of a float or double for numbers in Json. For example consider the following JSON document:

```
{"person":{"name":"Guillaume","age":33.4,"pets":["dog","cat"]}}
```

In Groovy 1.8.4 "age" would be represented as a float whereas in Groovy 1.8.5+ it's represented as a BigDecimal. I've created a [Java framework](https://code.google.com/p/rest-assured/) that uses the Groovy JsonSlurper under the hood so in order to maintain backward-compatibility I'd like to convert JSON numbers (such as 33.4) to float or double transparently. Having looked at the groovy-json source code I see that JsonSluper uses a JsonToken which is the one that creates a BigDecimal out of 33.4 in its "getValue()" method. This method is called by the JsonSlurper instance.

So what (I think) I want to do is to override the getValue() method in the JsonToken class to have it return a float or double instead. This is what I've tried:

```
    def original = JsonToken.metaClass.getMetaMethod("getValue")
    JsonToken.metaClass.getValue = {->
        def result = original.invoke(delegate)

        // Convert big decimal to float or double
        if (result instanceof BigDecimal) {
            if (result > Float.MAX_VALUE) {
                result = result.doubleValue();
            } else {
                result = result.floatValue();
            }
        }
        result
    }
```

The problem is that even though the code stated above is executed before `new JsonSluper().parseText(..)` the overridden "getValue()" in JsonToken is not called (the original getValue() method is called instead). But if I copy all code from the JsonSlurper class into my own class, let's call it JsonSlurper2, and do `new JsonSluper2().parseText(..)` the overridden method of "getValue()" *is* called and everything works as expected. Why is this? What would I have to do to avoid copying JsonSlurper to my own class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`JsonSlurper` is a Java class and therefore you are unable to override its methods via `metaClass`. See [this mailing list thread](http://groovy.329449.n5.nabble.com/Changing-metaclass-afects-Java-classes-td3355308.html).

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4035784/how-do-you-override-a-method-for-a-java-type-instance-with-groovy-meta-programmi) looks like it might have a way for you to do this.

Comment: Thanks that explains a lot.